# Different calling conventions in a same plain C function

Tags: c

I'm a harbour programmer and I need know how I can use different calling conventions in a same plain C function, because some DLL manufacturer use __stdcall and another use __cdecl but the functions are the same, example:

```
static int iCcv = 1;

HB_FUNC( foo )
{
   if( iCcv == 1 )
      typedef const char * ( __stdcall * pMYFUNC )( int n );
   else
      typedef const char * ( __cdecl * pMYFUNC )( int n );

   pMYFUNC funcMy = (pMYFUNC) GetProcAddress( hLib, "myProc" );

   const char * ret;

   if( funcMy )
       ret = funcMy( hb_parni( 1 ) );

   hb_retc( ret );
}
```

Comment: `if( iCcv == 1 )
      typedef const char * ( __stdcall * pMYFUNC )( int n );
   else
      typedef const char * ( __cdecl * pMYFUNC )( int n );`

This code is invalid in C. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/qYrTxqTb4

Comment: Use a system where there aren't different calling conventions?  If you can decide at compile time which convention is in use, it is easy.  If you have to decide at run-time, you need two versions of the code, one for the `__stdcall` version and one for the `__cdecl` version, with different function names.  Or you can try playing fast and loose with function pointers (possibly via a union type) but that's likely to lead to undefined behaviour.  You'll need to know, somehow, which convention a given DLL actually uses.  Guessing is unlikely to be a good idea.

Comment: Libraries are supposed to implement the ABI of the platform, you shouldn't have different calling conventions on the same OS.

Comment: @Barmar: There are platforms where multiple ABIs are in use. Even platforms where you can run 32-bit programs and 64-bit programs. You can even mix ABIs in one program.

Comment: `GetProcAddress()` returns a `FARPROC` which amounts to a generic function-pointer on that platform. So I think you need to cast it to the right type of function pointer at point of calling based on a flag so that code for both conventions is generated and the appropriate version is called at run-time.

Comment: @0___________ I wouldn't have guessed it's illegal; but in any case a name declared in the if or else branch would not be visible outside that branch. Not sure whether one could fiddle with a switch/case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something more like:

```
const int CALLING_STDCALL=1;
const int CALLING_CDECL=2;

typedef const char * ( __stdcall * pMYFUNC_STDCALL )( int n );
typedef const char * ( __cdecl * pMYFUNC_CDECL )( int n );

 //... The init() function where the library is linked...
 int init(FARPROC* my_func){
     *my_func=GetProcAddress( hLib, "myProc" );
     if(*my_func==NULL){
         return -1;
     }
     return 0; //Always check you loaded successfully!
 } 

//.. to call it

const char *CallMyFunc(FARPROC pFunc,int n,int conv){
    assert(pFunc!=NULL);//Should never get this far badly loaded.
    if(conv==STDCALL){
        pMYFUNC_STDCALL func=(pMYFUNC_STDCALL)pFunc;
        return pFunc(n);
    }
    assert(conv==CALLING_CDECL);//Good measure!
    pMYFUNC_CDECL func=(pMYFUNC_CDECL)pFunc;
    return pFunc(n);
}
```

The 'magic' here is that the code to call both conventions will be generated and the relevant version executed (assuming the flag was set correctly somehow - that wasn't in the question!).

There's not quite such a thing as a generic function-pointer (though you can round-trip function-pointers between function-pointer types) and there is no guarantee in C that `void *` will do(*). But on the Windows Platform `FARPROC` is provided for that purpose. Behaviour is defined in the platform for casting `FARPROC` to the correct type.

The above would benefit from a bit more type-safety by wrapping the pointer in a safety `struct` but I think that might bury the essence here.

Please. Please! Do put in a good dose of error checking and maybe elevate my debug `asserts()` to permanent release build checks.

Having worked at a place where things were a mountain of peripherals and DLLs that didn't always do what they said on their box any help in diagnostics is worth its weight in gold.

(*) though on modern platforms usually does.

Comment: Hi Persisty, this is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks for your brilliant idea.

Comment: it will not work with gcc as gcc will ignore the attributes

Comment: @0___________ gcc has never been quite at home on Windows. 
How do you vary calling convention on dynamically linked functions in gcc for Windows?

Comment: @Persixty never tried

Comment: @0___________ All solutions are likely implementation dependent but the points remain (a) C is statically typed in the sense you can't change them during execution and (b) you need to ensure code generation for both versions and then execute the relevant branch. It's a good example proving that the supposed C ABI is actually a myth.